# Who would be my reference: my supervisor or my manager?

Tags: references

I'm finishing from my current job, and would like to ask for a reference. Whom shall I ask a reference from: from my supervisor, or from my manager?

Comment: why not both?....

Comment: Depending on the size of company and country, don't be surprised if both direct you to the HR department.

Comment: @PeteCon Actually the HR told me if I need a reference they will provide me one, but I thought they meant through my supervisor/manager!! So, can I ask HR personnel to be my reference?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My relationship with my supervisor has been better and I have been closer to her, but I have a feeling she will refer me to the manager. I don't think my manager will say bad things about me, but I don't think he will say great things, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whom shall I ask a reference from: from my supervisor, or from my manager?

You could ask for reference to either of them. In fact, coworkers can also be used as references in some cases. Thus, it would be up to you to decide whom you want to ask.

You could always ask both if they would be willing to be your reference, and decide upon that (if only one of them agrees, then use that. If both agree, and your application only asks for one reference, chose either of those).

In practical terms one thing is asking for someone to be your reference and other is they actually agreeing to be your reference. In theory you should prefer to ask the one that you were closer to, and whom you had better relationship with.

Comment: I'm closer to my supervisor, but I'm suspecting she will refer me to the manager, with whom my relationship with hasn't been smooth. The HR said they can provide me a reference. What are the cases where coworkers be used as a reference?

Comment: @BlackMath go ahead and ask your supervisor instead of dwelling in suspicions. Seems that you also got HR as option if others are not possible. Coworkers can be used as reference any time you want, the real question is if using them will be of benefit to you. Some applications require more than one reference, and that would be a case where coworkers may serve as references (you actually spend more time and know more about how your coworkers work and behave rather than with your manager, thus they may know you better but their recommendation may "weight" less compared to your manager's).